# Convert MySQL columns into rows with pair

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database table like (attaching sample screenshot, as columns are many to make to make table here) -

[image]

As shown in image above, one single table `qbank` has both questions and options (answers). Earlier this seemed to be a good approach, but now learnt that it's not considered as good practice. So, I have created 2 different tables for questions and options (answers). Structure for my `answers` table is like -

```
ID
question_id
answer
correct
```

But I am not able to construct a single SQL query, by I can convert columns of `qbank` table anto `answers` table something like this -

```
+---------------+----------------------+
|Table_Answers  | Table_Qbank          |
+---------------+----------------------+
|ID             |  1                   |
+---------------+----------------------+
|question_id    | q_id (1)             |
+---------------+----------------------+
|answer_id      | option_01_text       |
+---------------+----------------------+
|correct        | option_01_is_correct |
+---------------+----------------------+
|ID             |  2                   |
+---------------+----------------------+
|question_id    | q_id (1)             |
+---------------+----------------------+
|answer_id      | option_02_text       |
+---------------+----------------------+
|correct        | option_02_is_correct |
+---------------+----------------------+
```

**i.e, first insert all 4 options and values if they are correct or not for the 1st question, then similarly insert queries for other question rows.**

I can make this work with PHP, but for 30000 question rows, I am trying to find a way if any SQL query can be customized to make this work from PHPMyAdmin itself.

Comment: You _could_ also handle this in MySQL, but this is really a presentation thing, and I would probably handle it from your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Revise your schema design.

Here's an example of a normalised schema:

```
questions
question_id, question
          1, What is the name of the current Prime Minister of India?
          2, What it the capital of India?

answers
answer_id, question_id, answer, is_correct
      101            1  Ram              0
      102            1  Shyam            1
      103            1  Kishan           0
      104            1  Mohan            0
      105            2  Jaipur           0
      106            2  Chennai          0
      107            2  Delhi            1
      108            2  Kolkata          0
```

Alternatively, you could simply say that the first answer is always the correct one, dispensing with the need for the is_correct column, or store the reference to correct answers in a separate table.

Comment: I have already revised the schema similar to what you have mentioned, but the problem I am facing is, how to copy my data from rows/columns of old table to new answers table?

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari You can use a series of UNIONs.